# Perform asynchronous tasks via subprocess without thread blocking

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, asynchronous, tkinter, subprocess

The aim of my code is to produce a progress bar via tkinter, and whilst progress is being made with my progress bar, I would like to extract a .7z file via subprocess calling upon 7-zip.

After extracting the 7-Zip files, I would like to shutdown the computer. The first problem with this, is that the line of code after the line that extracts the 7-Zip files, executes and shuts down the computer without waiting.

In light of this, I will need to wait until the extraction is finished, before proceeding. A catch-22 with this, is that I cannot block any of my threads, because I have my progress bar still running. With my current code, I am able to wait for the extraction, but the progress bar won't appear until the extraction is finished, because all threads are being blocked.

Asynchronously speaking, in a way, how am I able to achieve my goal?

Here's my progress bar code:

```
class FinishSetup(tk.Toplevel):

    # progress bar to simulate finishing set up
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal",
            length=200, mode="determinate")
        self.progress.pack()

        self.bytes = 0
        self.maxbytes = 0

        self.size_top()

    def start(self):
        self.progress["value"] = 0
        self.maxbytes = 100000
        self.progress["maximum"] = 100000
        self.read_bytes()

    def read_bytes(self):
        self.bytes += 100
        self.progress["value"] = self.bytes
        if self.bytes < self.maxbytes:
            # read more bytes after 100 ms
            self.after(100, self.read_bytes)

    def size_top(self):
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        ws = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = self.winfo_screenheight()

        w = 200
        h = 22

        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.iconify)
        self.lift()
        self.attributes('-topmost', 'true')
        self.overrideredirect(True)
```

And my main code that extracts the 7-Zip files:

```
archive_name = 'files.7z'
maps_dir = 'output'

extract = subprocess.Popen('"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" x ' + archive_name + ' -o' + maps_dir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in iter(extract.stdout.readline,''):
    print(line.rstrip())

print('Finished')
```

I need to be able to run my progress bar `FinishSetup().start()`, whilst extracting my 7-Zip files, and after that's done, shutdown my computer.

I've been trying to get this right for a whole day but I'm being driven to the realization that this just may not be possible.

Please let me know your thoughts and if there's anything else I should be trying.

Comment: This should be possible, but what you need to take into account is that tkinter doesn't *play nice* with multithreading in an application. It's not that it's impossible, it's just not going to be fun for you to program, godspeed brave soul.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do the extraction in a separate thread or process. This second thread or process can communicate back with the GUI through a queue. You can poll the queue on the GUI side by using `after` to continually reschedule a function which checks the queue every few hundred milliseconds.